# Safely overloading stream operator>>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stream

There's a ton of information available on overloading `operator<<` to mimic a `toString()`-style method that converts a complex object to a string. I'm interested in *also* implementing the inverse, `operator>>` to deserialize a string into an object.

By inspecting the `STL` source, I've gathered that:

```
istream &operator>>(istream &, Object &);
```

would be the correct function signature for deserializing an object of type `Object`. Unfortunately, I have been at a loss for how to properly implement this - specifically how to handle errors:

1. How to indicate invalid data in the stream? Throw an exception?
2. What state should the stream be in if there *is* malformed data in the stream?
3. Should any flags be reset before returning the reference for operator chaining?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. How to indicate invalid data in the stream? Throw an exception?

You should set the `fail` bit. If the user of the stream wants exception to be thrown, he can configure the stream (using `istream::exceptions`), and the stream will throw accordingly. I would do it like this, then

```
stream.setstate(ios_base::failbit);
```

2. What state should the stream be in if there is malformed data in the stream?

For malformed data that doesn't fit the format you want to read, you usually should set the `fail` bit. For internal stream specific errors, the `bad` bit is used (such as, if there is no buffer connected to the stream).

3. Should any flags be reset before returning the reference for operator chaining?

I haven't heard of such a thing.

---

For checking whether the stream is in a good state, you can use the `istream::sentry` class. Create an object of it, passing the stream and `true` (to tell it not to skip whitespace immediately). The sentry will evaluate to `false` if the `eof`, `fail` or `bad` bit is set.

```
istream::sentry s(stream, true);
if(!s) return stream;
// now, go on extracting data...
```

Comment: Also make sure you check the `fail` bit before you try doing anything. If it's set already, just return the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, especially using the `fail` bit instead of exceptions. In addition to setting the fail bit, must I make any guarantees about the contents of the stream? E.g., should the stream be unchanged if I set the `fail` bit?

Comment: That's essentially what I was going to say, but you answered faster!  I'd add that the right answer is found by looking up what the existing implementations do, which is what you're describing.  Also, I would note that there is no such thing as malformed data, so much as a wrong format to read it; in that case, you want to make sure the variable is unchanged, and (if you set the fail bit and not the bad bit) that no characters have been lost from the stream.

Comment: Not consuming any char from the stream for a badly formatted input is about impossible.  You'd need arbitrary backtrack.  The common behavior is to consume the valid prefix.

Comment: How would you recommend handling situations where the prefix is valid, but the actual data is not?

Comment: In the operator>>, like it is done for the simple types (at first though floating point are the only one in this case): return a failure and consume the valid prefix.  In user code, you can provide better diagnostic to your user by reading a full line and then parsing it from a stringstream.  But there is a time when going to a full lexer/parser designed for error reporting is the thing to do.

Comment: I would just consume the valid prefix. And keep it at that. If you need tentative parsing without actually consuming anything, then *I* would not use iostreams anymore. They are just too unflexible for this. I would use C streams or the low-level `read` interface of iostreams, and create my own read-ahead buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Some additional notes:

- when implementing the operator>>, you probably should consider using the
  bufstream and not other overloads of operator>>;
- exceptions occuring during the operation should be translated to the
  failbit or the badbit (members of streambuf may throw, depending on the
  class used);
- setting the state may throw; if you set the state after catching an
  exception, you should propagate the original exception and not the one
  throwed by setstate;
- the width is a field to which you should pay attention.  If you are
  taking it into account, you should reset it to 0.  If you are using other
  operator>> to do basic works, you have to compute the width you are passing
  from the one you received;
- consider taking the locale into account.

Lange and Kreft (*Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales*) conver this in even
more details.  They give a template code for the error handling which takes
about one page.

Comment: Why do you suggest using `bustream` instead of other overloads (e.g. `istream`? I'll be sure to check out Lange and Kreft's work - it sounds just like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi, I see that both the Michael and AProgrammer are not so active so if someone else sees this: Why is bustream better than overloading?

Answer (score 0):

As for flags, I don't know if there is any standard somewhere, but it is a good idea to reset them.

Boost has neat raii wrappers for that: [IO State Savers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html)

Comment: I don't think this is designed to be used in extractors but by user code.

Comment: I don't see the difference. They work on input streams as well, so if you want to set flag back to what it was you can, better than manually anyway. Extractor that affects stream in weird ways is essentially broken.